# Fluid container 2 rows

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, rows

I am attempting to create 2 rows inside a fluid container.

The first row is to be 12 columns across all devices, whilst the second row is to be split into 4, 4, 4

Currently the second row is placed below the container and I cannot work out where the issue is caused.

Any help would be appreciated (I'm fairly new to HTML)

Thank you

[Please see the image here for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N91zg.png)

```
**<!-- Mid text (First row heading text)-->**

            <div class="container-fluid" style="padding: 0px !important">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="mid-text">
                            <div class="mid-text-heading"> Placeholder Text </div>
                                <div class="mid-text-heading2"> 
                                    <p>Placeholder Text</p></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>



            **<!-- Mid image 1 'Responsive (2nd row starts here) -->**


                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                       <div class="mid-image1">
                            <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="responsive-image-1.png" alt="image1">
                            <div class="mid-image1-text"> Responsive Website </div>
                            <p>Placeholder Text</p>

                        </div>
                    </div>




             **<!-- Mid image 2 'Responsive' -->**



                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                        <div class="mid-image2">
                            <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="placeholder-image.png" alt="image2">
                                <div class="mid-container2.png"> Placeholder Text </div>
                                    <p>Placeholder Text</p>

                        </div>
                    </div>



             **<!-- Mid image 3 'Responsive' -->**



                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                        <div class="mid-image3">

                            <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="mid-container3.png" alt="image3">
                            <div class="mid-image3-text"> Placeholder text </div>
                            <p>Placeholder Text</p>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

/* Middle Text */

.mid-text {

```
width: 100%;
height: 500px;
text-align: center;
font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
font-weight: 300;
font-size: 40px;
background-color: #ffd33d;
```

}

.mid-text .mid-text-heading {

```
margin-top: 0px;
padding-top: 30px;
text-align: center;
color: black;
font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
font-weight: 300;
```

}

.mid-text .mid-text-heading .mid-text-heading2 {

```
margin-top: 0px;
padding-top: 30px;
text-align: center;
color: red;
font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
font-weight: 100;
```

}

.mid-image1 {

```
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
font-weight: 300;
font-size: 20px;
text-align: center;
```

}

.mid-image1 .mid-image1-text {

}

.mid-image2 {

```
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
font-weight: 300;
font-size: 20px;
text-align: center;
```

}

.mid-image2 .mid-image2-text {

}

.mid-image3 {

```
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
font-weight: 300;
font-size: 20px;
```

}

.mid-image3 .mid-image3-text {

}

Comment: What other CSS is being applied? The code as presented above outputs rows as expected though I wouldn't recommend overriding the `container` padding in the fashion you're doing.

Comment: Hi @RobertC I have updated the above with the CSS code I am using, I have left the .mid-image#-text blank for the moment intentionally.

Thanks

Comment: Did you notice that on your `.mid-text` class (what you use in your first row) you're specifying a fixed height of 500px?

Comment: @RobertC I have removed the height from the .mid-text class and added height for the fluid-container and this seems to have worked fine.

Thank you for the help :)